# Issue capturing user audio on Safari / iPhone through react web app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, safari, web-audio-api, mediarecorder

I am unable to capture audio recording from my React web app front end.
While it works on Chrome browsers (Windows, Mac and Android phones), there seems to be some issue when trying to capture audio in the following scenario -

1. Chrome browser **ONLY ON** iPhones
2. Safari browser on Mac OS and iPhones

Sharing the functions that are capturing and transmitting the audio to the server.

```
const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
const [hasStarted, setHasStarted] = useState(false);
const [chatStatus, setChatStatus] = useState(false);
const id = useRef(uuid());
const audioChunksRef = useRef([]);

const startRecording = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
      const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        audioChunksRef.current.push(event.data);
      };

      mediaRecorder.start();
      setMediaRecorder(mediaRecorder);
      setIsRecording(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = async () => {
    if (mediaRecorder) {
      mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {

        const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunksRef.current, {
          type: 'audio/mp3',
        });
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('audio', audioBlob, 'audio_recording.mp3');
        formData.append('id', id.current);

        const response = await fetch(`${URL}/upload-audio`, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          credentials: 'include',
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Fetch error:', error);
          throw error; // Re-throw the error to handle it in the onstop handler
        });
        const { lastMessage, chatStatus } = await response.json();
        console.log(lastMessage);
        setResponseText(lastMessage);
        setChatStatus(chatStatus);
        audioChunksRef.current = [];
        mediaRecorder.stream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        setMediaRecorder(null);
      };
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      setIsRecording(false);
    }
  };
```

Comment: If it works on other plattforms. I would assume this is a Rights issue. Does the enable microphone Dialog pop when you load on iphone?

Comment: yes the dialog box does popup asking for permissions

Comment: Does enable that Change anything?

Comment: No, it still does not record the audio even after allowing permissions.